# Upload image on Webkit Cordova - Android 4.4

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webkit

I am building a web_app using Cordova.

With the image tag :
 `<input  type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg" value="Take a picture"/>`

When I click on the input tag it let me choose images on device.

It works fine on **iOS 7 , iOS 8** with **Safari** and **Android 4.4** with **Google Chrome**.

My problem is, when user open my web app on device. They can do some steps on it. But suddenly the have some other task to do like "answer calls, reply text messages".

After that, they back to my web app. In Safari or Google Chrome, my app will reload. The user must start at the beginning.

I solved this problem by using Cordova. It works well.

Except on Android 4.4 the WebView component looks like doesn't support choosen file when I click on input tag.

I dont want to use **Cordova Camera plugin**. Because with my current implementation It's hard.

Does anyone have the same problem with me?

Comment: input file is broken on android 4.4, you have to use a plugin, like camera plugin or file chooser plugin